# Having Https issues

Tags: https, security-certificate

My https website is not loading on my BlackBerry device, its reading it as an insecure website.  It was working before I added the security certificate. Any advise on how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Sorry, there's really too little detail here and too many variables for users to be able to help you. Take a look at this support article from BlackBerry:  ["Access Denied: Insecure SSL Request" appears in the BlackBerry Browser when untrusted HTTPS sites are browsed](http://support.blackberry.com/kb/articleDetail?ArticleNumber=000022536).

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's a great place for me to start.  I will as well get more detail on the problem.  I appreciate your direction on this.

Comment: No problem, as that article indicates, be sure to check that the domain name in your certificate exactly matches the one in your URLs, and not mentioned there, that all resources in the page you're requesting have the  `https` protocol or are relative to that. You can use Developer Tools in browsers like Chrome for the later. Lastly, check for any regular expressions in the BlackBerry Administration Service console (i.e., Cause 1). Good luck.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again, you've definitely put things into focus.  Best regards.